# How to return value from the thread back to main function without using blocking function in C++/C

Tags: c++, sockets, timer, routes

I am making a routing protocol and I need 30 seconds non-blocking timers for each neighbor which I implemented through threads and here is the example code. However, I check it's value 2 or 0 in order to discriminate between whether thread got timed out or stopped by me (I'm stopping the thread  by setting value of the structure variable.)

Problem is that, my value is not passing back to main function and the only solution which I know of join which is blocking but I need non-blocking for routing protocol. Any help will highly be appreciated. Thanks.

```
struct arg_struct 
{
    int Wait_30sec;
    int Alarm_port[5];
    int index;
};

void* start_timer(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;
    int i;
    clock_t endwait;
    i = args->index;
    endwait = clock() + args->Wait_30sec * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    while (clock() < endwait && args->Alarm_port[i] == 0)
        ;

    if(args -> Alarm_port[i]==0) 
        args -> Alarm_port[i]=2;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: In whatever structure you're using to tell the thread what to do, leave a space for the thread to store the result.

Comment: You may like to use a library for event dispatching, such as [libevent](http://libevent.org/). Using it you can handle multiple sockets and timers all in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the value should be reflected to the main thread, as you passed the address of it to the thread. I would suggest to the debug the code like so:

1) First inspect your call to the thread, and verify that you send the address of the correct struct-variable. Then see if you inspect the correct variable for the result.

2) Did you set the `index` variable of your struct before calling the thread?

3) Perhaps your thread doesn't finish due to a bug in the final value you wait for. Try printing the current value and end value to stdout or to a file, and see if the loop terminates.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response. Infact, I have used the cout along with the code (not shown in the code) and I'm sure that my value from main function gets passed there and I managed to stop it as well by changing the value of this Alarm_Port[i] in the main function but whatever I edit in this thread doesn't reflect back. I tried to search on the web and came out, I have to use join which is blocking and I want to avoid that.